# How to do something the instant all threads are complete?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Let's say I want to have n threads running and I want to output something when ALL threads complete. Here are the methods I've tried:

```
//This uses a ThreadGroup called tGroup
while(tGroup.activeCount() > 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This next is just with a while loop and an ArrayList storing Threads

```
boolean alive = true;
int count = 0;
while (alive) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        if (!threads.get(i).isAlive()) {
            count++;
        }
        if (count == numThreads) {
            alive = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you have each thread notify when it finishes, and have your main just wait, each time it's notified, see if any threads are left, if so, wait again, until none are left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through all your threads and `join()` each one. The `join()` will block on any unfinished thread until it finishes.

Comment: Doesn't join make it so no threads can run until the one before it is complete? If so, this is not what I want. I want all threads to run at the same time and when the last one running is complete, I want to output something.

Comment: @BackpackOnHead - No, Ted is correct.  All started threads will continue running, uninterrupted by this code, anyway.  As each thread stops, this will "open" each `join()` "gate".  Once all gates are open, you can proceed to your "want to output something" statement.

Comment: Why not just use a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) instead? Isn't it built specifically for just this situation?

Comment: join() causes the current thread to wait for the thread that is joined() to complete.  So your controller thread (to coin a term) can do start, start, start, start, and then join on the first of those.  When the statement after the join completes, the first thread is done.  You can code it as join, join, join, join, and the statement after that last join will execute when all threads are done.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I had my joins in the same foreach that added them to my arraylist and that was causing an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to use is a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) as this was built specifically for just this type of situation. Each worker thread will notify the latch when it is complete, and then any threads that have called `await()` on the latch will hold operation until the count down is complete. Please look at the sample code in the API link I've given above to see how easy and flexible this is to use.

**Edit:**
Oops, I guess I was too late in posting this. But regardless that you accepted the other answer,  you still owe it to yourself to check this out as it is quite elegant and easy to use.

For example:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class CountDownLatchEg {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int threadCount = 8;
      CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(threadCount);
      System.out.println("Start all threads");
      for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
         new Thread(new MyRunnable(latch, i)).start();
      }
      System.out.println("All threads started");
      try {
         latch.await();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      System.out.println("All threads finished");

   }
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
   private CountDownLatch latch;
   private Random rand = new Random();
   private long delay;
   private int id;

   public MyRunnable(CountDownLatch latch, int id) {
      this.latch = latch;
      delay = (rand.nextInt(4) + 1) * 1000;
      this.id = id;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      System.out.println("Start thread: " + id);
      try {
         Thread.sleep(delay);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
      System.out.println("End thread: " + id);
      latch.countDown();
   }
}
```

Comment: A down side to `CountDownLatch` is that it requires every thread to call `countDown()`. If for some reason a thread dies without making that call . . . trouble. Plus, technically, the threads are not guaranteed to have died, just to have made the call.

Comment: True, but the `countDown()` could (should?) be called in a finally block, and the freezing issue is no different for your solution, I think.

Comment: A `finally` block would be good insurance, yes. If all threads are programmed like that, there's no freezing issue. In my solution, when a thread dies--regardless of how--the corresponding `join()` will return. What I had in mind with the last comment was not freezing so much as that a thread can hang around in an alive state an indefinite time after calling `countDown()` simply because of the vagaries of thread execution. Calling `join()` (or going back to something like OP's original code of calling `isAlive()`) is the only way to know for sure that a thread is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean this:

```
boolean alive = true;
int count = 0;
while (alive) {
    count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        if (!threads.get(i).isAlive()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == numThreads) {
        alive = false;
    }
}
```

?